# Read/ Write from structs in c

Tags: c, struct

I'm creating a rugby league table and the last piece of functionality is to read from a file (I think .txt would be easiest) and writing back to it at the end of the program (or on prompt).

I know there is a lot of help around, but I don't fully understand it. I don't want someone to code it for me, just to explain my error.

Here is what I've got so far. NB, I've commented the code with anything I'm unsure of.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct leagueTable {
int id;
char *name;
int win;
int loss;
int draw;
int points;
};

int main(){

int l, n = 1, i = 1, r = 1, a, b, d, e, f;
char c;
struct leagueTable team[19];

FILE *myfile = fopen("leagueTable.txt", "r");
if (myfile != NULL) {
    printf("Error Reading File!\nWill Exit Application!\n");
    exit (0);
}
while (fscanf(myfile,"%s %d",strcpy(team[r].name, %team[r].id) != EOF) {
    r++;
}
for (r = 1; r < 19; r++) {
    printf("%i %s %i %i %i %i", team[r].id, team[r].name, team[r].win, team[r].loss, team[r].draw, team[r].points);
}

fclose(myfile);

return 0;
}
```

And here is the content of the file

```
England 1
Ireland 2
Scotland 3
Wales 4
France 5
Italy 6
Germany 7
Uraguay 8
Belgium 9
USA 10
Mexico 11
Australia 12
New Zealand 13
Denmark 14
Sweden 15
Belize 16
South Africa 17
Algeria 18
```

And my error

```
assignment.c: In function ‘main’:
assignment.c:29:55: error: expected expression before ‘%’ token
 while (fscanf(myfile,"%s %d",strcpy(team[r].name, %team[r].id) != EOF) {
                                                   ^
assignment.c:29:76: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘{’ token
 while (fscanf(myfile,"%s %d",strcpy(team[r].name, %team[r].id) != EOF) {
                                                                        ^
assignment.c:51:1: error: expected expression before ‘}’ token
 }
 ^
./cScript.sh: line 4: 24101 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) ./assignment
```

I think the FILE *myfile and the 4 lines following are correct, but its just the assigning the contents of the file to the struct.

Currently the file only has whole strings and a single int, but it will have multiple int values and split strings (i.e "South Africa").

How can I get it to just assign the values in the file to the struct?

Comment: The code does not compile. One reason, what is `%team[r].id` as an argument for `strcpy` supposed to do? Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem. And why are you passing `strcpy(team[r].name, %team[r].id) != EOF` as an argument for `fscanf`? The code is nonsense.

Comment: So I found that  at this link :- https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/274590/read-file-into-structure

I have no idea what %team[r].id part does, if it was &team[r].id, I would say it assigns the value to that particular variable.

Comment: There's nothing like `strcpy(team[r].name, %team[r].id)` on that page. If you understand basic C syntax, you should realize that what you wrote is nonsense, especially as an argument to `fscanf()`.

Comment: I get this error when I compile it.  `main.c: In function 'main':
main.c:25:51: error: expected expression before '%' token
 while (fscanf(myfile,"%s %d",strcpy(team[r].name, %team[r].id) != EOF) {
                                                   ^
main.c:25:72: error: expected ')' before '{' token
 while (fscanf(myfile,"%s %d",strcpy(team[r].name, %team[r].id) != EOF) {
                                                                        ^
main.c:35:1: error: expected expression before '}' token
 }
 ^

exit status 1
   `

Comment: It seems like you've somehow combined several statements from the code on that page into one statement that's totally meaningless.

Comment: `strcpy` does not even return `EOF`. It returns a pointer to the destination string. You have unmatched parentheses.

Comment: I've been coding C (no other language experience) for around 2 weeks, this is the first time I've ever used (or seen) a `fscanf()`. 

Why is it nonsense? Point me to where I can learn this properly, all I've done so far is use Google, which as you can see, hasn't worked.

Comment: Process strings split by a space : [Read entire line and divide by last space](http://ideone.com/vJsEvE)

Comment: `"%s %d"` will not scan `New Zealand 13` as hoped.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (fscanf(myfile,"%s %d",strcpy(team[r].name, %team[r].id) != EOF) {
```

Two major problems here:

1. There's a `%` before `team[r].id`. You probably wanted an `&`.
2. `team[r].name` has not yet been assigned a value. Before you try to put a string where it points, you have to make it point somewhere useful.

Comment: "Make it point somewhere useful", is that allocating enough memory to it using malloc? I've seen that kicking about in a few tutorials I've used/ seen, but the last I found (in the comments of the original post) looked far easier and I somewhat understood.

Thanks for the advice

Comment: Allocating memory with `malloc` would be one way. Reading into a fixed buffer and then using something like `team[r].name=strdup(buffer);` would be another. It's up to you, but you have to assign it a sensible value before you attempt to use its value. The important thing to understand is that you declared a pointer, not a string, and its value is the where it points.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz You're not going to mention that using `strcpy()` from a number to a string makes no sense?

Comment: @Barmar I guess that could be added to the list. ;)

Answer (score 0):

First, the `name` member of `leagueTable` should be an array, not a pointer:

```
struct leagueTable {
    int id;
    char name[20];
    int win;
    int loss;
    int draw;
    int points;
};
```

Then, you seem to have mixed together several lines in your call to `fscanf()`. And when you're scanning into an integer variable, you have to pass a pointer using `&`, not `%`. It should be:

```
while (fscanf(myfile,"%s %d", team[r].name, &team[r].id) != EOF) {
    r++;
}
```

And array indexes start at `0`, not `1`, so you should initialize `r = 0`, not `r = 1`.

Comment: Is there a reason for the `name` member to be an array (I understand why)? Previous tutorials I've followed (and have worked) use the method I have, which is why it's remained until now. Does this change when you try to assign values from files rather than hardcoding?

Second point, completely understand, Thanks :)

The only reason I've initialised it like this is when I call `team[1].name`, it will return England without the need of `team[x].id`. In future cases, I assume starting at 0, but retaining the `id` member would be best practice?

Thanks for the advice.

Comment: If it's not an array, you need to call `malloc()` to allocate memory for each name. What's the point of that, when you can simply put the array directly in the structure?